# setting div element value in html

Tags: html

How to set values for the below div block (setting values in '?' placeholder).

```
 <table>
 <tr>
  <td class="tfArrive " valign="top">
    <div class="tfArrAp" id="txt3">
         ? </div>
 </td>    </tr>

</table>
```

I have tried with following scenario, but not working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('txt3').innerHTML = "TEST";
</script>
```

Comment: [Your code is indeed working](http://jsfiddle.net/TdDYy/). Did you execute it before `#txt3` was available in the DOM?

Comment: the code is correct, its probably the order of call, try alerting the innerHTML , do you get an error while trying to get the object with id txt3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is working perfectly, it's just that you need to be sure that you are placing the script after the HTML is rendered, so first you need to print the tables out and than use the script tag, because if you place the script before the `id="txt3"` has rendered, it won't change anything as `onload` the script didn't find any, so this should be the order...

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="tfArrive " valign="top">
      <div class="tfArrAp" id="txt3">
         ? 
      </div>
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById('txt3').innerHTML = "TEST";
</script>
```

> Side Note : If you are using HTML5, you don't need
>   `type="text/javascript"` anymore, as now, default is JavaScript

Comment: You might be right. My scenario is , Im getting three queryString Param from index.html to result.html where im wrote the script code under</scrip> element. can you assist me how to store the received param and display it in <div> block.

Comment: @Manu Not a JS pro here, but I showed you where you were going wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#txt3').html("New Text");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure your page is loaded before you manipulate it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('txt3').innerHTML = "TEST";
}
</script>
```